# CDI 1.1 Interceptor / InterceptorBinding called twice

Tags: cdi, interceptor, java-ee-7, payara

I've built a simple ear application consisting of an EJB and a WAR module. I'm using CDI interceptor to intercept the call to JSF actions to do some operation. Everything is working fine except for a strange behaviour that arises when I annotate the action method using the interceptorbiding annotation. To be more precise, here is the code:

This is the interceptor biding class

```
@Inherited
@Documented
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface SecurityCheck {
}
```

This is the interceptor class:

```
@Interceptor
@SecurityCheck
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public class SecurityCheckInterceptor implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    SecurityService secutiyService;        

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object securityIntercept(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        String target = // build the fully qualified method name from ic
        System.out.println("---- ENTER: ["+target+"]");        
        Object out = ic.proceed();
        System.out.println("---- EXIT:  ["+target+"]");
        return out;     
    }
}
```

And these are the two alternative of usage of the interceptor in my JSF bean class:

```
// METHOD N. 1
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class IndexController implements Serializable {
    ...

    @Interceptors({SecurityCheckInterceptor.class})
    public void doAction() {
        System.out.println("indexController.doAction()");           
    }
}
```

and

```
// METHOD N. 2
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class IndexController implements Serializable {
    ...

    @SecurityCheck
    public void doAction() {
        System.out.println("indexController.doAction()");           
    }
}
```

when I use the method N. 1 the output is as follow:

```
---- ENTER: [it.univaq.we2018.tutor.controller.IndexController.doAction()]    
indexController.doAction()
---- EXIT:  [it.univaq.we2018.tutor.controller.IndexController.doAction()]
```

so everything is as expected, but using Method n.2 (which I prefer) the output is as follow:

```
---- ENTER: [it.univaq.we2018.tutor.controller.IndexController.doAction()]
---- ENTER: [it.univaq.we2018.tutor.controller.IndexController.doAction()]
indexController.doAction()
---- EXIT:  [it.univaq.we2018.tutor.controller.IndexController.doAction()]
---- EXIT:  [it.univaq.we2018.tutor.controller.IndexController.doAction()]
```

The interceptor is called twice in a "nested" fashion.
Is this a bug? Have I missed something?
I'm using Java 1.8_172, Payara 5.181, NetBeans 8.2 and JavaEE 7 profile. The application is based on the javaee7 maven archetype. All the annotation are CDI and not the JSF ones (eg. ViewScoped).

Thank you.

Comment: This is baffling. Can you print out stack trace at the `indexController.doAction()` and see the sequence of calls?

Comment: It might be a bug. Have you tried with Payara 4.181 too? Or with any other Java EE 7 implementation like TomEE or WildFly?

Comment: I'm just downloading Payara 4.1.2.181 and WildFly 13.0.0Final to do a check...just to guess...seems that the ic.proceed() raises another call to the interceptor... I will post results with the other two appserver asap...thank you.

Comment: I just made a simple test with weld-se and i didn't see any nested execution. But probably it is may be because the bean was not `@ViewScoped`

Comment: Worked like a charm in Payara 4.1.2.181 (though it raises many warnings that seems to be fixed in Payara 5 but not back-ported to v4) and also in WildFly 13.0.0Final... Seems to be a bug in the version 5...

Comment: ...incredible! I switched again to Payara 5 and now it works as expected with the binding annotation. Cannot explain why...I simply switched 3 times the appserver and hit Run...

Comment: I guess you did not re-built all parts of your ear before redeploying and hence had both interceptors somehow active? Could also be that you activated that interceptor via `beans.xml` as well as `@Priority` (but in that case Weld should only invoke it once from what I know).

Comment: No, if you enable interceptor through the priority annotation and the beans.xml, weld documentation says both will be registered and you will have 2 interceptors

Comment: I cleaned all the code, deleted all deployments, rebuilt everything and redeployed. Now it works perfectly. Thank you all for your help!